# jQuery Удаление элементов по таймеру

Tags: jquery, анимация, callback

Например, есть такой обработчик:

```
$(document).on('click', '.alert', function() {
   $(this).fadeOut(timeout, function() {
      $(this).remove();
   }
}
```

При клике на соответственном `div`, он плавно затемнит этот элемент и в конце уберёт его из DOM как, я понимаю.
Но, например, есть ещё один обработчик

```
$(document).on('triggerevent', function() {
  $(document).each('.alert', function() {
    $(this).remove()
  }
}
```

И он по некоторому событию сразу убирает из DOM все элементы с классом `alert`.
Если в процессе анимации будет вызван он, не сломается что-либо в работе скрипта? Ведь в калбек первого обработчика в `this` пойдет несуществующий объект. 
Подобные ситуации нужно рассматривать самому, или же jQuery (Zepto) сам об этом позаботится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(this).remove()
```

удаляет элемент совсем, в цикле

```
$(document).each('.alert', function() {
```

он не появится.

В процессе анимации так же ничего не испортится, элемент просто исчезнет.

Но я бы сделал одну вещь, чтобы не портить эффект. Когда начинается анимация, поставьте какой-нибудь особый класс элементу, и исключите элементы с этим классом из удаления по triggerevent. Тогда элемент не исчезнет резко посреди анимации.

```
$(document).on('click', '.alert', function() {
   $(this).addClass('no-remove');
   $(this).fadeOut(timeout, function() {
      $(this).remove();
   }
}
$(document).on('triggerevent', function() {
   $(document).each('.alert', function() {
     if (!$(this).hasClass('no-remove')) $(this).remove();
   }
}
```

Comment: Немного подробней. Данные формы аяксом отправляются на сервер. Если заполненные поля содержит ошибки, то понятно нужно их вывести возле каждого поля. По клику на предупреждении, нужно его убрать. И понятно, нужно убрать все предупреждения при повторной отправке формы.

Comment: А проблема в чем?

Comment: Та уже ни в чём, напрасно я беспокоился. Если так можно, то всё в порядке.

Comment: На всякий случай попробуйте получить экземпляр элемента и дважды выполнить для него $(element).remove(). По идее, jQuery не должен заругать.